# Finding the maximum distance travelled

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a set of gps points travelled by each vehicle. I am trying to retrieve the maximum distance travelled by a vehicle in each trip.

Data:

```
    VehicleId       TripId          Latitude            Longitude
    121             131             33.645              -84.424
    121             131             33.452              -84.409
    121             131             33.635              -84.424
    121             131             35.717              -85.121
    121             131             35.111              -85.111
```

From the above dataset, my resultset should be like this, in which the startlat and startlong for each combination of VehicleId and TripId should be the same, whereas
the EndLat and EndLong should keep changing, so that I can find out the maximum distance travelled by each vechicle from the starting point.

```
    VehicleId       TripId          StartLat            StartLong       EndLat          EndLong
    121             131             33.645              -84.424         33.645              -84.424
    121             131             33.645              -84.424         33.452              -84.409
    121             131             33.645              -84.424         33.635              -84.424
    121             131             33.645              -84.424         35.717              -85.121
    121             131             33.645              -84.424         35.111              -85.111
```

I tried with the below query but I get the error "Correlated subqueries that reference other tables are not supported unless they can be de-correlated, 
such as by transforming them into an efficient JOIN". Any help would be appreciated. I tried the below query, it works for a specific VehicleId and TripId, but I am not able 
to generalise it for all combinations.

```
    SELECT
      a.VehicleId,
      a.Tripid,
      a.Latitude AS StartLat,
      a.Longitude AS StartLong,
      b.Latitude AS EndLat,
      b.Longitude AS EndLong,
      a.DateTime
    FROM
      `Vehicles` AS a
    JOIN
      `Vehicles` AS b
    ON
      a.VehicleId = b.VehicleId
      AND a.Tripid = b.Tripid
    WHERE
      a.VehicleId = 550340912
      AND a.Tripid = 18006167 AND
      a.DateTime IN (
      SELECT
        MIN(DateTime)
      FROM
        `Vehicles`
      WHERE
        VehicleId = 550340912
        AND Tripid = 18006167)
```

Answer (score 1):

Distance traveled is somewhat ambiguous in relation to latitude/longitude pairs, but I'm going to assume Haversine distance for this solution. Here's the complete query, including setup, building on my answer from [a previous SO post about Haversine distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068651/haversine-distance-in-bigquery).

The idea is to get the start and end for each trip in association with the vehicle ID (creating an array of all the entries), then use a subquery over the array to select the entry with the greatest distance. If you wanted some other metric, you could substitute it for the `HAVERSINE` function that I used.

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION RADIANS(x FLOAT64) AS (
  ACOS(-1) * x / 180
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION RADIANS_TO_KM(x FLOAT64) AS (
  111.045 * 180 * x / ACOS(-1)
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION HAVERSINE(lat1 FLOAT64, long1 FLOAT64,
                               lat2 FLOAT64, long2 FLOAT64) AS (
  RADIANS_TO_KM(
    ACOS(COS(RADIANS(lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
         COS(RADIANS(long1) - RADIANS(long2)) +
         SIN(RADIANS(lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat2))))
);

WITH Vehicles AS (
 SELECT 121 AS VehicleId, 131 AS TripId, 33.645 AS Latitude, -84.424 AS Longitude, DATETIME "2017-03-12 12:00:00" AS DateTime UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 33.452, -84.409, DATETIME "2017-03-12 12:01:00" UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 33.635, -84.424, DATETIME "2017-03-12 12:01:32" UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 35.717, -85.121, DATETIME "2017-03-12 13:00:56" UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 35.111, -85.111, DATETIME "2017-03-12 20:30:47"
)
SELECT
  (SELECT vehicle_and_distance
   FROM UNNEST(vehicles_and_distances) AS vehicle_and_distance
   ORDER BY vehicle_and_distance.distance DESC LIMIT 1).*
FROM (
  SELECT
    ARRAY_AGG(
      STRUCT(VehicleId,
             HAVERSINE(start_location.Latitude, start_location.Longitude,
                       end_location.Latitude, end_location.Longitude) AS distance)
    ) AS vehicles_and_distances
  FROM (
    SELECT
      VehicleId,
      TripId,
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Latitude, Longitude)
                ORDER BY DateTime ASC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS start_location,
      ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Latitude, Longitude)
                ORDER BY DateTime DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS end_location
    FROM Vehicles
    GROUP BY
      VehicleId,
      TripId
  )
  GROUP BY TripId
);
```

Edit: for the sake of completeness, it's interesting to think about total distance traveled along the route as well, rather than just straight line distance between the start and end points. Here is another query that computes the sum of Haversine distance traveled along the route by looking at successive pairs of points:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION RADIANS(x FLOAT64) AS (
  ACOS(-1) * x / 180
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION RADIANS_TO_KM(x FLOAT64) AS (
  111.045 * 180 * x / ACOS(-1)
);
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION HAVERSINE(lat1 FLOAT64, long1 FLOAT64,
                               lat2 FLOAT64, long2 FLOAT64) AS (
  RADIANS_TO_KM(
    ACOS(COS(RADIANS(lat1)) * COS(RADIANS(lat2)) *
         COS(RADIANS(long1) - RADIANS(long2)) +
         SIN(RADIANS(lat1)) * SIN(RADIANS(lat2))))
);

WITH Vehicles AS (
 SELECT 121 AS VehicleId, 131 AS TripId, 33.645 AS Latitude, -84.424 AS Longitude, DATETIME "2017-03-12 12:00:00" AS DateTime UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 33.452, -84.409, DATETIME "2017-03-12 12:01:00" UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 33.635, -84.424, DATETIME "2017-03-12 12:01:32" UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 35.717, -85.121, DATETIME "2017-03-12 13:00:56" UNION ALL
 SELECT 121, 131, 35.111, -85.111, DATETIME "2017-03-12 20:30:47"
)
SELECT
  TripId,
  vehicle_and_distance.*
FROM (
  SELECT
    TripId,
    ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(VehicleId, total_distance)
              ORDER BY total_distance DESC)[OFFSET(0)] AS vehicle_and_distance
  FROM (
    SELECT
      VehicleId,
      TripId,
      (SELECT
         SUM(HAVERSINE(
               Latitude, Longitude,
               vehicle_locations[OFFSET(off - 1)].Latitude,
               vehicle_locations[OFFSET(off - 1)].Longitude))
       FROM UNNEST(vehicle_locations) WITH OFFSET off
       WHERE off > 0) AS total_distance
    FROM (
      SELECT
        VehicleId,
        TripId,
        ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(Latitude, Longitude)
                  ORDER BY DateTime ASC) AS vehicle_locations
      FROM Vehicles
      GROUP BY
        VehicleId,
        TripId
    )
  )
  GROUP BY TripId
);
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I have an UDF that calculates the distance between two gps points. The problem I am currently facing is I am not able to generalize by above query. I tried with your query but it does not provide the maximum distance travelled by each vehicle in a trip.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What is the result that you get instead? And are you calculating distance between the start and end or between all sequential points?

Comment: I am calculating the distance between start point and all the other sequential points for each group. In my case, the distance between (33.645              -84.424) and all other sequential points for each group of vehicleid and tripid.

Comment: Can you try running just the inner query from the second sample (the part with `SELECT VehicleId, TripId, (SELECT SUM(HAVERSINE(...`) and check the output? In theory that should give you the distance for each trip/vehicle pair. If your distance function can return negative values, you may need to use `ABS`.

Comment: Thanks Elliott. My apologies for not stating the question correctly. I tried running the inner query as well but I did not get the intended results. So I have added a separate thread by stating my question clearly.