# Find the nearest weather station for multiple points in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a table (i.e. Table 1) with millions of rows of lat-lon coordinates. I want to determine the nearest weather station to each coordinate using weather station data (i.e. Table 2). I then want to create another table (i.e. Table 3) that joins Table 1 and the column of Station Id's of the nearest weather stations from Table 2.

e.g

**Table 1: My Table**

| Row | Lon | Lat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -40.3 | 80.1 |
| 2 | -41.1 | 80.5 |
| 3 | -42.2 | 79.2 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Table 2: Weather Station Table**

| Station Id | Lon | Lat |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | -340.31 | 80.11 |
| 222 | -41.10 | 80.51 |
| 333 | -42.21 | 79.21 |
| 444 | -40.30 | 80.11 |
| 555 | -341.11 | 80.51 |
| ... | ... | ... |

**Desired Result**

**Table 3: MY TABLE with Station ID**

| Row | Lon | Lat | Station ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | -40.3 | 80.1 | 444 |
| 2 | -41.1 | 80.5 | 222 |
| 3 | -42.2 | 79.2 | 333 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

I've come across this link on how to calculate the nearest weather station to an arbitrary lat-lon coordinate.
[HAVERSINE distance in BigQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42068651/haversine-distance-in-bigquery)

I'm stuck however in extending it to calculate multiple arbitrary points without resorting to using loops outside BigQuery (i.e. Python). Is there a BigQuery way to address this? Thank you

Comment: What is data size of Table 2.? No. of rows?

Comment: solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53989172/sql-finding-the-closest-lat-lon-record-on-google-bigquery?rq=1

Comment: Perfect! These links addressed my question. Thanks